# Supervisor loop and queue runner

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to fill queue using an external thread loop. Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Provider:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count += 1
        print("call provider", self.count)

d = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[2, 1])
queue = tf.FIFOQueue(3*2*10, dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[[1]])
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many(d)
#tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op]))

provider = Provider()


sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir='/tmp/test_provider')

with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    sv.loop(1, provider)
    sv.start_queue_runners(sess)

    for i in range(100):
        print("run", i)
        time.sleep(20)
```

This code is not complete but what I expect here is the following output

```
call provider 1
run 0
call provider 2
call provider 3
call provider 4
call provider 5
call provider 6
call provider 7
call provider 8
call provider 9
call provider 10
call provider 11
call provider 12
call provider 13
call provider 14
call provider 15
call provider 16
call provider 17
call provider 18
call provider 19
call provider 20
call provider 21
run 1
call provider 22
call provider 23
call provider 24
call provider 25
```

This works as long as the line

```
#tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op]))
```

is commented. Once I decomment it, it doesn't work anymore. My next step is to put the queue inside my callable object in order to fill it. Any ideas on why it breaks ?

Comment: What's the error? I'm guessing it would complain about `d` not being fed

Comment: It's not really an error. When I add this line the callable is not being called anymore. I expect it to be called every 1 second.

Comment: One problem is that evaluating `enqueue_op` requires `d` to be fed, but default queue runner doesn't support `feed_dict`, so it should throw an error. There's [feeding_queue_runner](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/dataframe/queues/feeding_queue_runner.py) and placeholder_with_default for these kinds of cases

Comment: I took a look a `feeding_queue_runner` and `in_memory_source.NumpySource`. Is it possible to have a NumpySource that changes over time ? Same dimensions but different values ?

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using queue runner, just use regular session.run, in separate thread if necessary

Comment: In fact, not using the queue runner solves my problem. So,  I just not understand why in this case I don't have to use a queue runner ?

Comment: A queue runner allows calling `session.run` in a loop. Generally you don't need queue runners ever and can do regular `session.run` instead, queue runners they are just helpful wrapper around `session.run` -- check my queues talk for explanation -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/tree/master/queues_talk

Comment: Great. Thank you!